# Have they edited the turning water to wine scene in 'Now You See Me'?

Tags: alternate-version, now-you-see-me

Movie: [Now You See Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/?ref_=nv_sr_2)

[image]

The scene was the first meeting between Mark Ruffalo and Morgan Freeman, in the latter's office. In the first version of the scene, which I saw on DVD, all of them are sitting in a sofa, and Morgan Freeman turns a glass of water to wine by magic. Now after a year or so, I saw the same movie on TV, and they have changed the scene. It's now at a restaurant, they are sitting around a table, and there is no water turning to wine scene.

Have I mixed something up here or are there different versions of this scene shown on TV and released on DVD? Why was this done and which of those was shown in theatres?

Comment: Maybe you saw the [extended cut](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/alternateversions)?

Comment: Nope, I don't recall watching the extended cut. Also, I think extended cut show you more footage rather than the same footage shot differently.

Comment: If you were watching it on a channel that has regular commercial breaks, they may have edited the scene out for time. Network and cable channels tend to cut 'unnecessary' scenes to make room for ads.

Comment: @jld: There is a difference between editing a scene and replacing a scene.. This was replacing.. And both the scenes seem to be of equal length..

Comment: Are you possibly confusing it with the scene in Bruce Almighty?

Comment: I wouldn't put it past a TV channel to edit out a Jesus reference. They are touchy about not offending religious folk.

Comment: @Tivep: Nope, I am not

Comment: i watched the film and it showed thaddeus with red dye stuck to his hand

Answer (score 4):

As Walt guessed, this is one of the [differences between the theatrical version and the extended cut](http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=450000):

> Rhodes first contact with Alma and Thaddeus Bradley is different. In the Theatrical Version, the scene takes place at a restaurant. In the Extended Version, Rhodes and Alma are being informed about Bradley's importance by his assistent while she's leading them to his office. He started as a magican and was really good at it which is being ironically noted by Rhodes. When they're finally sitting at the table with Bradley, he offers them wine. Rhodes refuses but Alma would like some, to Rhodes astonishment. Thaddeus grabs a water glass and shakes it. A split second later, it's filled with red wine. Rhodes is impressed. The subseuqent conversation remains basically unchanged.